# Create a timestamp from variables in SQL and format string to time

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I have a table containing 100's of entries -

I have since after import, updated the columns to include a timestamp.

The data is given to me by XMl and imported into DB

I have 3 columns in the data.

A date in `date` format.

A time in `varchar` format,

And a timestamp.

The timestamp is created out of the date and time put together, which works fine in PHP for all new entries, but I need to update the old entries to have a timestamp as well.

Examples :

The new entries comes in like this

`ANK_BD` = 2020-02-13

`ANK_BT` = 0945

`ANK_Timestamp` = 2020-02-13 09:45:00

But the old entries look like this

`ANK_BD` = 2020-02-13

`ANK_BT` = 0945

`ANK_Timestamp` = null

Now I want to run a SQL query to update the old entries.

But I simply can not figure out how I can create the time out of the `ANK_BT`

Something like `UPDATE 'tablename' SET 'ANK_timestamp'= 'ANK_BD'+'ANK_BT' WHERE 'ANK_timestamp' is null`

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mysql `TIMESTAMP` function:

```sql
UPDATE 'tablename' SET 'ANK_timestamp' = TIMESTAMP(ANK_BD, CONCAT(ANK_BT, '00'))
WHERE 'ANK_timestamp' is null
```

It need concat to update correct timestmp. '0945' is converted to '00:09:45' but '094500' is converted to '09:45:00'

Hope this helps

Comment: This worked almost instantly, I had to change ' to ` in phpmyadmin for it to work for some reason, but thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate the values together and use `str_to_date()`:

```
UPDATE tablename
    SET ANK_timestamp = str_to_date(concat(ANK_BD, ANK_BT), '%Y-%m-%d %h%i')
    WHERE ANK_timestamp is null;
```

Do not use single quotes around column names.

Comment: I need to study SQL some more - Not knowing how to concatonate, and not knowing a simple function like str_to_date is embarrising.. Thank you for the input, But went with the timestamp function

Comment: @Stender . . . That answer is incorrect because identifiers are surrounded by single quotes.

Comment: That is not fair - The question was regarding the possability of making the data into a timestamp - not whether or not you could format my strings - You both answered correctly, with different methods. you just didn't have any formatting errors. - And since i mentioned that it was a timestamp field, I would think that using the `TIMESTAMP` function would actually be *more*  correct.

Comment: The single quotes from my original code, was put there since SO uses -> ` <- to suggest that code is comming, but the tables were surrounded by that is phpmyadmin